# How do I expand expressions involving complex numbers?

Tags: complex, algebraic-manipulation

I am trying to do the following:

```
Expand[(A g + n)^2 Conjugate[A g + n]^2, Element[{A, g, n}, Complexes]]
```

The goal is to expand and get all the terms of $(A g + n)^2 ((A g + n)^*)^2$ where the variables are complex numbers. Ideally, in the form of either $A A^*gg^* + \ldots$ or $|A|^2 |g|^2 + \ldots$.

Unfortunately, all I get as an output is:

```
==> (A g+n)^2 ((A g+n)^*)^2
```

How do I get Mathematica to actually expand this expression in terms of the complex variables?

`ComplexExpand[]` is not useful because it splits up the real and imaginary parts which is going too far for what I want.

Comment: "`ComplexExpand[]` is not useful..." - ...because you did not supply the *second argument* and the `TargetFunctions` setting: `ComplexExpand[(A g + n)^2 Conjugate[A g + n]^2, {A, g, n}, TargetFunctions -> Conjugate]`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Is there anyway to get Mathematica to collect $AA^*$ into $|A|^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in comment by J.M., use the option [`TargetFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetFunctions.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = (A g + n)^2 Conjugate[A g + n]^2;

expr2 = expr // ComplexExpand[#, {A, g, n},
    TargetFunctions -> Conjugate] &

(* A^2 g^2 Conjugate[A]^2 Conjugate[g]^2 + 
 2 A g n Conjugate[A]^2 Conjugate[g]^2 + n^2 Conjugate[A]^2 Conjugate[g]^2 + 
 2 A^2 g^2 Conjugate[A] Conjugate[g] Conjugate[n] + 
 4 A g n Conjugate[A] Conjugate[g] Conjugate[n] + 
 2 n^2 Conjugate[A] Conjugate[g] Conjugate[n] + A^2 g^2 Conjugate[n]^2 + 
 2 A g n Conjugate[n]^2 + n^2 Conjugate[n]^2 *)
```

To convert `sym * Conjugate[sym]` to `Abs[sym]^2`

```
expr3 = expr2 //. Times[a___*(sym_)^m_.*Conjugate[sym_]^n_.] :>
   Times[a*Abs[sym]^2*sym^(m - 1)*Conjugate[sym]^(n - 1)]

(* Abs[A]^4 Abs[g]^4 + 4 Abs[A]^2 Abs[g]^2 Abs[n]^2 + Abs[n]^4 + 
 2 n Abs[A]^2 Abs[g]^2 Conjugate[A] Conjugate[g] + 
 2 n Abs[n]^2 Conjugate[A] Conjugate[g] + n^2 Conjugate[A]^2 Conjugate[g]^2 + 
 2 A g Abs[A]^2 Abs[g]^2 Conjugate[n] + 2 A g Abs[n]^2 Conjugate[n] + 
 A^2 g^2 Conjugate[n]^2 *)
```

Verifying equivalency

```
expr == expr2 == expr3 // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks. There's a lot to unpack in there (since I am not very familiar with the Mathematica language).